# Rails attr_accessor from different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Following were my home_controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @products = Product.public_active.order('random()').limit(6).includes(:product_attachments).includes(:product_reviews)
  end
end
```

and my product.rb model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_attachments, allow_destroy: true
  attr_accessor :product_display
  attr_accessor :product_overview_url

  def set_extra_attributes
    self.product_overview_url = self.product_attachments[0].attachment.medium.url
  end

  def set_cover_photo
    self.product_display = self.product_attachments.find(self.cover_id).attachment.url
    end
  end
```

In my home views `app/views/home/_product_section.html.erb`, I cant access the `product_display`

```
<div class="row">
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="img-holder">
      <a href="<%= product_path product %>">
        <img src="<%= product.product_display %>" alt="<%= product.name %>" style="width: 100%;">
      </a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But I can access `self.product_overview_url` from my `app/view/products/index.html.erb` page template. Is there relationship I need to make so `home_controller` can access `product.rb` model? Thanks!!

Comment: Please show the product_display method and the error message you're receiving. From your code it looks like you are accessing a class method called product_display. Also, in future please make an effort to format your code better, you'll get more responses if your code is easy to read.

Comment: @margo hi, there is no error at all in console. I think `<%= product.product_display %>` in view is not recognise the `product_display`. After inspecting, the `src` field is empty

Comment: Can you confirm in the console that the product instance has a product display attribute?

Comment: @margo how can i confirm this via console (sorry I am bit new in using rails in console)? btw, Is not all product instance can access the product model attributes?

Comment: Of course, Product instances can access their attributes. Open a terminal window, run rails console. Then you can manually run your code e.g. Product.first or products = Product.public_active.order('random()').limit(6).includes(:product_attachments).includes(:product_reviews); products.each{|p| puts p.product_display}. Its a great way to test and debug.

Comment: @margo ok I just tried, and I get nil but if I tried as follow `products = Product.first` and then `products.product_attachments[0].attachment.medium.url` do return result, which is url of image

Comment: What do you think that tells you? Have you created products in your d/b with product_display attributes? Do some more debugging in the console. You can run any ruby code in the console as well as have access to your rails app. (btw to quit the console, type exit.)

Comment: @margo `NoMethodError: undefined method `display_product' for #<Product:0x007fe7155f4200>` How can this possible? Since `display_product` is `attr_accessor`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109645/discussion-between-margo-and-d3bug3r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the set_extra_attributes and set_cover_photo methods, self is not required as these are instance methods referencing instance attributes.

```
def set_extra_attributes
  product_overview_url = product_attachments[0].attachment.medium.url
end

def set_cover_photo
  product_display = product_attachments.find(cover_id).attachment.url
end
```

end

You need to ensure that the product_display is set to something.